# React Javascript Multiple Arrays to an Object of Arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, data-manipulation

I have a set of arrays that have multiple bits of data that I want to arrange into a new array of data.
This is what I have:

```
const dateArray = ["9/13/2022", "9/13/2022", "9/13/2022", "9/13/2022","9/13/2022"]
const timeArray = ["00:00", "00:01", "00:02", "00:03", "00:04"]
const integerArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

This is what I want:

```
{
    row0: ["9/13/2022", "00:00", 1],
    row1: ["9/13/2022", "00:01", 2],
    row2: ["9/13/2022", "00:02", 3],
    row3: ["9/13/2022", "00:03", 4],
    row4: ["9/13/2022", "00:04", 5]
}
```

Thanks for any info you could provide, I've tried to do map, reduce and group but I haven't had exactly what I want to come back and I'm losing my mind keeping track of what I've tried.

Comment: Will all the three arrays have equal number of items. If that is the case you can just create a for loop on length of any array. Then insert an object rowIndex as dateArray[i], timeArray[i] and integerArray[i]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const dateArray = ["9/13/2022", "9/13/2022", "9/13/2022", "9/13/2022","9/13/2022"]
const timeArray = ["00:00", "00:01", "00:02", "00:03", "00:04"]
const integerArray = [1,2,3,4,5]

const res = dateArray.reduce((acc, _, i, dates) => ({
  ...acc, [`row${i}`]: [dates[i], timeArray[i], integerArray[i]]
}), {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: cool but can you please explain what happened there? what is `_` for example?

Comment: @ChrisG as linked in the docs, the second param is the current-value which we're not using in the solution. `_` is just a common-practice to tell that this variable is to be ignored. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @MajedBadawi, thank you so much for the prompt answer and the breakdown afterwards, I tried so many attempts of reduce and see now why my code flopped, thank you!